# windowDidLoad() never called using storyboards for mac

Tags: xcode, storyboard, swift

I've just played around with the new mac storyboard-feature included in Xcode 6. I've set up a new OS X-project using storyboards and swift, then I've created a new file `MainWindowController.swift`, created the initializer `init(coder: NSCoder!)` (because otherwise the compiler warns me) and hooked everything up in the `Main.storyboard` file (set the `MainWindowController`-class for the WindowController in the inspector).

Everything compiles fine, my Window with the specified `window content`-view opens. But the code I've written in the `windowDidLoad`-function is never be called. Let it just something like:

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
    super.windowDidLoad()

    println("Executed")
}
```

I've also tested if my initializer is called - it is.

Does anybody has a clue? I've never used storyboards intensively on iOS before, maybe I miss something substantial.

Comment: make sure the class for that view is set to MainViewController in the identity inspector

Comment: I've set the ViewController-Class as well in IB. But what matters that for the WindowController?

Comment: my mistake a misread the question.

Comment: From what I tested, I can't get this to work at all. Storyboard, simple Nib, override loadView, never gets called

Comment: So you think it's a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Yosemite, NSViewController has been promoted with powerful new features to make it work with Storyboards. Meanwhile, NSWindowController got demoted. With Storyboards, windows are no longer loaded from a nib, so windowDidLoad() doesn't get called anymore.

It makes sense for the window itself to become less important, in favor of a more powerful view it actually contains. My other answer on this page shows how to set up an AppDelegate to customize the window appearance. There's more detail [on another page here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24543911/3799712), about using an AppDelegate to implement some of the things you might previously have done in an NSWindowController.

However, if you only wanted to catch windowDidLoad() as a way to customize the appearance options of the window, it is ***very easy*** to do that in Interface Builder, by simply adding them as User Defined Runtime Attributes to the NSWindow object. You don't need to subclass NSWindowController or write any code at all. Just plug in these values to the NSWindow object via the Identity Inspector pane to achieve the same effect shown in the AppDelegate example code:

```
Keypath: titlebarAppearsTransparent, Type: Boolean, Value: Checked
Keypath: titleVisibility, Type: Number, Value: 1
Keypath: styleMask, Type: Number, Value: 32783
```

Look in the headers to determine the actual numeric values of the constants.

( for example: NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden = 1 )

Of course, you can't specify individual bits of the styleMask, but it's easy enough to add them all together and get a single number to specify the style.

Comment: The User Defined Runtime Attributes method works fine for my project without storyboards, but doesn't seem to do anything when I use storyboards. What might I be missing?

Comment: As of "El Cap", at least, windows loaded from storyboards do call the window controller's windowDidLoad().  Perhaps it was a bug that got fixed?

Answer (score 2):

Remove everything except the Application scene from the Main.storyboard file, and instead, create a new Application.storyboard for the application window. Implement an application delegate class and connect it to the Application object in Main.storyboard. Use this class to instantiate the window controller and set up custom options for the application window.

```
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(notification: NSNotification) {

        let storyboard = NSStoryboard(name: "Application", bundle: nil)
        applicationController = storyboard.instantiateInitialController() as? NSWindowController
        if let window = applicationController?.window {
            window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true
            window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden
            window.styleMask |= NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask
            applicationController!.showWindow(self)
        }
    }

}
```

Rather than subclassing NSWindowController, use the ViewController.swift subclass of NSViewController that Xcode creates for you automatically with the project.

In the storyboard, notice how there's a Relationship that connects the "window content" to the ViewController. So, the ViewController can now do things that you might previously have done in a window controller.

The ViewController.swift file will already have a default override of viewDidLoad() that will be called when the window loads, just as you were expecting windowDidLoad() to be called if it were an NSWindowController subclass.

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    println("Executed")

}
```

Comment: Ok, but if I try to do something like `self.view.window.titleVisibility = NSWindowTitleVisibility.Hidden` in viewDidLoad I get Bad-Access.. I have to do that after the window did load in the WindowController.
Second case is to retrieve items from the toolbar, with storyboards i have to do that in my WindowController, because I can't even connect Toolbar-Items to my ViewController in IB.

Comment: I updated my answer above, explaining how I did that via an application delegate.

Comment: At least right now, there doesn't seem to be a way of intercepting the Main.storyboard's instantiation of it's initial window controller. Instantiating a separate Storyboard via an AppDelegate class lets you set up the desired window options.

Comment: Also right now (Xcode6 beta 2), if you create a new Document-based Storyboard app, the Document.swift file incorrectly uses the same Main.storyboard for documents. The old pattern was to create a separate Document.xib instead of Main.xib for the document window. So, create your own Document.storyboard to do the same thing.

Comment: Regarding your Toolbar, that AppDelegate class will automatically receive IBActions sent by toolbar and menu items from any window. Just define the methods and they'll appear in IB for you to connect to. After all, the Toolbar really is interacting with your application in its entirety, rather than just a window object, isn't it?